# php/html: One auto variable from one php file to another

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, xampp

I created forms that automatically generates an ID for a user. I did most of the work with that variable in `phpadmin` not `php`. I put `NULL` for it in `php`. However, I am creating two pages, first one asks the user to register and then asks him when he is entering a place and leaving. I wish to make it such that when the user registers and is moved to the next page, his ID is also called in that file. This is how I tried to put the variable in the first table:

```
$_SESSION['idofuser'] = $_GET["id"];
```

How I put it in the 2nd file that is to call the value of this variable:

```
$ids=$_SESSION['idofuser'];
```

Can someone identify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

from PHP documentation, you need to start the session using `session_start()` or `session.auto_start` is set to 1 in php.ini to make it accesssible to the next page or until the session die.

see more details in [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) about session.